# RStudio error 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Tags: r, statistics, heatmap

I have this dataset here, and essentially I want to create a heatmap with Latitude and Longitude values on the rows and columns and the heat colors showing the concentration of Enterococci.

[image]

But for some reason this code here:

```
bacteria_data$Enterococci..cfu.100ml. = as.numeric(bacteria_data$Enterococci..cfu.100ml.)

heatmap(bacteria_data$Enterococci..cfu.100ml.,Rowv = bacteria_data$Longitude, Colv = bacteria_data$Latitude)
```

produces a:

```
Error in heatmap(bacteria_data$Enterococci..cfu.100ml., Rowv = bacteria_data$Longitude, : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

I've tried searching solutions online but none of them looked intuitive. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're getting an error because your `x` (`bacteria_data$Enterococci..cfu.100ml.`) is not a numeric matrix. You've converted it to numeric successfully but it's a vector rather than a matrix.

Error shown when a vector is provided:

```
heatmap(1:10)
```

```
Error in heatmap(1:10) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

Which is the same one you're getting. If we convert this to a matrix we get a different, more helpful error:

```
heatmap(matrix(1:10))
```

```
Error in heatmap(matrix(1:10)) : 
  'x' must have at least 2 rows and 2 columns
```

Which means we're at least on the right track. If we do actually run it with multiple rows we get what we expected:

```
heatmap(matrix(1:10, nrow = 2))
```

which produces the heatmap.

I suggest you work out what exactly your rows and columns should be in the clustering algorithm - are you clustering locations by lat and lon? Then you'll need to pivot_wider somehow because basically `heatmap` expects data in wide format while it looks like yours are in long.